# Stripe is not returning PaymentIntentId

Tags: .net, stripe-payments, stripes

I i am using using Stripe.Checkout; everything is working fine but I can not get PaymentIntentId

I tried to change the stripe mode but what I want is only for testing

Comment: Hello, please check [ask] and [edit] your question to include some code related to your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Stripe Checkout, you won't have a PaymentIntent, but will have a CheckoutSession instead. Only after the Checkout Session is successfully paid by the customer, you will have a [successful PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#delayed-notification) inside the checkout.session.completed webhook event.